# Android : drop down a list of items without a spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, drop-down-menu, android-spinner

I am new to Android and I get confused when having to organize a layout that retrives data.
I want to be able to drop down below a general item a list of other items when clicking on it and be able at the same time to switch each one of them. I would like to do this properly by retrieving the list of items from a `string-array`:

```
<string-array name="general1">
    <item>ITEM 1</item>
    <item>ITEM 2</item>
</string-array>
```

I don't want to use a spinner.

It's hard for me to see how to resolve this problem. 
Please any idea?

[image]

Comment: What you need is [Android Expandable List View](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to be able to drop down below a general item a list of other
>   items when clicking on it and be able at the same time to switch each
>   one of them

What you need is [Android Expandable List View](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)